# How do I wait for sub-process to complete in Linux

Tags: c, linux, popen, alsa

I need to play a wave file using `aplay`. However, my wave files are few seconds in length. So I plan to play them in loop for certain period of time. `aplay` does not seem to have loop options.  From my C file create a sub-process using `popen()`  The playback is working fine. But the difficulty is that I can't monitor when the wave file playback is completed so that I can start over.

```
popen("aplay WaveFile","r");
```

How do I know when this command has finished playback?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alternatively you could use a library such as SDL to play audio independently of the driver (alsa, pulse, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) manpage:

> The `pclose()` function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by `wait4(2)`.

If you don't want to be blocked on `pclose`, you may try [non-blocking reads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36673972/7233423) on the pipe returned by `popen`, until you get an EOF which means the process has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for various option of aplay from the man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay)

one of the option is -d which is

```
-d, --duration=#
Interrupt after # seconds. A value of zero means infinity. The default is zero, so if this option is omitted then the arecord process will run until it is killed.
```

So if you know the wave file play duration you can give that number with -d.
There are many ways to calculate the wave file length like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5a92be69-3b4e-4d92-b1d2-141ef0a50c91/how-to-calculate-duration-of-wave-file-from-its-size?forum=winforms)

Comment: I saw this in man page but the operation does not match. Even if use `-d 0` option, it terminates after wave file ends.

Comment: `The default is zero, so if this option is omitted then the arecord process will run until it is killed.` means recording will continue indefinitely. Not playback.