# how to establish a non blocking read from unix pipes?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, ipc

Let‘s assume we have a pipe `int InPipe[2];`. How can you read the input until the pipe is empty  without blocking when the whole available Data input was read?

I know this question has been asked several times, but I couldn’t assemble a suitable function.

This is my Code so far:

```
int InPipe[2];
char buffer[1024];
int rc;
while (true){
    read(InPipe[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    fprintf(stdout, “%s“, buffer);
    bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // Clearing Buffer
}
```

Any Ideas, Suggestions, Code Snippets

Comment: Read it on a separate thread.

Comment: Look up "non-blocking I/O"

Comment: Also, please note that [bzero is deprecated](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero) and that you should use memset instead.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673972/non-blocking-read-on-pipe

Comment: The most important point is to ensure that the write end of the pipe is closed correctly.  That normally means that the reading process has closed the write end of the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reading from a pipe**

> Attempts to read from a `pipe` that is currently empty **`block`** until at
> least one byte has  been  written  to  the  `pipe`.  If  the  write  end
> of  a  pipe  is  closed,  then  a  process reading from the pipe will
> see `end-of-file` (i.e., `read()` returns 0) once it has read all remaining
> data in the `pipe`.

taken from linux interface programming.

You cant! the process reading from the pipe will be blocked in this situation.

Due to people comments, i am adding this section:

we can use a `pipe` to allow communication between two processes. To con-nect two processes using a pipe, we follow the `pipe()` call with a call to `fork()`.  immediately after the `fork()`, one process closes its descriptor for the write end of the pipe, and the other closes its descriptor for the read end. For example, if the parent is to send data to the child, then it would close its  read  descriptor  for  the  pipe,  `filedes[0]`,  while  the  child  would  close  its  write descriptor for the pipe, `filedes[1]`, then the code for this will be:

```
int filedes[2];    

if (pipe(filedes) == -1)   /* Create the pipe */        
    errExit("pipe");    

switch (fork())        /* Create a child process */
{                              
case -1:        
    errExit("fork");    
case 0:             /* Child */       
    if (close(filedes[1]) == -1)            /* Close unused write end */            
        errExit("close");        

    /* Child now reads from pipe */        
    break;    

default: /* Parent */        
    if (close(filedes[0]) == -1)            /* Close unused read end */            
        errExit("close");        
    
    /* Parent now writes to pipe */        
    break;    
}
```

Comment: Well, as suggested by @john, reading the pipe on a separated thread does the trick, hence your answer is wrong.

Comment: @MaximeB - i know this trick but this is not OP question.

Comment: Well, even in a single threaded mode non-blocking functions remains relevant (see O_NONBLOCK flag, [select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), [poll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html),...), which is what was asked by the OP.

Comment: Your statement is fine to make a point, but as one of the comments suggests looking up non-blocking I/O, maybe you could also show OP how to fix the problem by including an illustration of something that works along these lines

Comment: i appreciate your comments. really! but i am trying to give him the most accurate answer. without any further suggestions. if you think you need to expand the answer i encourage you to write your own answers. go ahead please. thanks again.

Comment: I am taking your suggestion to put my own answer, but I wanted you to know that I am not the down voter.  I did not offer my suggestion to be a pest, but thought it would be an easy opportunity for you to improve what I think starts out to be a decent answer.

Comment: i take you comments and improved my answer. thank you all.

Comment: @ryyker - thank you! i have added a code snippet that ilustrate the usage with 2 processes

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your useful Explanations ;)

Comment: @BigSur - my pleasure. we need to think the one and only [Michael Kerrisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Kerrisk). all my answer almost have bee taken from his book. if my answer was useful, i would be glad if you vote up and accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of key things mentioned in the comments, i.e. non-blocking IO, and performing the read in its own thread, along with some other suggestions.  [The example here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/) goes into detail explaining its architecture.  Only the code section is reproduced below as I believe it to be a decent illustration of several of these comments. The example code is commented throughout.  Read them, they serve as a good tutorial:

```
// C program to demonstrate use of fork() and pipe() 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // We use two pipes 
    // First pipe to send input string from parent 
    // Second pipe to send concatenated string from child 
  
    int fd1[2];  // Used to store two ends of first pipe 
    int fd2[2];  // Used to store two ends of second pipe 
  
    char fixed_str[] = "forgeeks.org"; 
    char input_str[100]; 
    pid_t p; 
  
    if (pipe(fd1)==-1) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" ); 
        return 1; 
    } 
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" ); 
        return 1; 
    } 
  
    scanf("%s", input_str); 
    p = fork(); //Note - the return of fork can be less than, greater
                //       than or equal to zero.  Each is significant in
                //       knowing how to direct program flow, as shown 
                //       in this section...
  
    if (p < 0) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed" ); 
        return 1; 
    } 
  
    // Parent process 
    else if (p > 0) 
    { 
        char concat_str[100]; 
  
        close(fd1[0]);  // Close reading end of first pipe 
  
        // Write input string and close writing end of first 
        // pipe. 
        write(fd1[1], input_str, strlen(input_str)+1); 
        close(fd1[1]); 
  
        // Wait for child to send a string 
        wait(NULL); 
  
        close(fd2[1]); // Close writing end of second pipe 
  
        // Read string from child, print it and close 
        // reading end. 
        read(fd2[0], concat_str, 100); 
        printf("Concatenated string %s\n", concat_str); 
        close(fd2[0]); 
    } 
  
    // child process 
    else
    { 
        close(fd1[1]);  // Close writing end of first pipe 
  
        // Read a string using first pipe 
        char concat_str[100]; 
        read(fd1[0], concat_str, 100); 
  
        // Concatenate a fixed string with it 
        int k = strlen(concat_str); 
        int i; 
        for (i=0; i<strlen(fixed_str); i++) 
            concat_str[k++] = fixed_str[i]; 
  
        concat_str[k] = '\0';   // string ends with '\0' 
  
        // Close both reading ends 
        close(fd1[0]); 
        close(fd2[0]); 
  
        // Write concatenated string and close writing end 
        write(fd2[1], concat_str, strlen(concat_str)+1); 
        close(fd2[1]); 
  
        exit(0); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Awesome Tutorial ;)

Comment: @BigSur -   Actually, credit really goes to the author on the link provided. I only added one comment in the code, the rest is from the link.  But glad it helped.