# How to write to stdout without being blocking under linux?

Tags: linux, pipe, nonblocking

I've written a log-to-stdout program which produces logs, and another exe read-from-stdin (for example filebeat) to collect logs from stdin. My problem is that my log-to-stdout speed may burst in a short period which exceeds read-from-stdin can accept, that will blocking log-to-stdout process, I'd like to know if there is a Linux API to tell if the stdout file descriptor can be written to (up to N bytes) without being blocked?

I've found some comments in [nodejs process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

```
In the case they refer to pipes:
They are blocking in Linux/Unix.
They are non-blocking like other streams in Windows.
```

Does that mean under Linux it's impossible to do non-blocking write on stdout? Some documents reference non-blocking file operate mode (https://www.linuxtoday.com/blog/blocking-and-non-blocking-i-0/), does it apply to stdout too? Because I'm using third-party logging (which expect stdout working at blocking mode), can I check stdout writable in non-blocking mode (before calling logging library), and then switch stdout back to blocking mode, so from logging library perspective, stdout fd still works as previously? (if I can tell stdout will be blocking, I'll throw output, since not being block is more important than output complete logging in my usage)

(Or if there is a auto-drop-pipe command, which can auto drop lines if pipeline will block, so I can call
`log-to-stdout |  auto-drop-pipe --max-lines=100 --drop-head-if-full | read-from-stdin`)

Comment: Suppose you can do non-blocking writes. What are you planning to do for when the stream reports that the buffers are full and tye write would block? Drop the data on the floor?

Comment: yes, drop them. because not being blocking is more important than complete log in my usage.

Comment: I see. (1) It is actually not important whether your file is stdout or anything else. stdout is not special. (2) Pipes can be set to non-blocking mode no problem, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673972/non-blocking-read-on-pipe).  (3) You *cannot* check before logging because there is no guarantee you will be able to write as many bytes as the log wants. Your best bet is probably to write `auto-drop-pipe` yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've read the reference question, if I understood correctly, it shows a non-blocking retry read from a pipe, and I'm considering writing auto-drop-pipe myself. but I still have question about "You cannot check before logging because there is no guarantee you will be able to write as many bytes as the log wants"  even if I can know the exactly number of bytes to write before logging is not enough (suppose just a simple single thread application)?

Comment: Most people want non-blocking reads rather than non-blocking writes, so that's what you would find. But there is actually no difference. Set it to non-blocking mode, try writing in chunks of 512 bytes or less, if it EWOULDBLOCK, drop the chunk. "even if I can know the exactly number of bytes to write" -- There is no API that says how many bytes you *could* write without being blocked. You can only try writing them, and then either succeed or fail with EWOULDBLOCK.